# Add one year with months to dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm stuck at trying to generate a dropdownlist where i have both year and month showing.

The dropdown must have 1 year showing like below.

- "Nov 2012"
- "Oct 2012"
- "Sep 2012"
- "Aug 2012"
- "Jul 2012"
- "Jun 2012"
- "May 2012"
- "Apr 2012"
- "Mar 2012"
- "Feb 2012"
- "Jan 2012"
- "Des 2011"

That should be one year of months.

I'm using this javascript to submit on the dropdownlist:

```
$('.dropdownMonthYear').change(function ()
        {
            var values = $('.dropdownMonthYear').val().split(",");
            var month = values[0];
            var year = values[1];
            window.location = '/Garage/Top10Cars.aspx?month=' + month + '&year=' + year;
        });
```

Codebehind:

```
month = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["month"]);
            year = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["year"]);
```

Anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: What is the problem exactly? And why do you directly convert month to int?

Comment: Are you generating the months in C# or javascript?

Comment: If the separator between a month and a year is a space,why are you splitting on a comma?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one way using [`Linq`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397933.aspx):

```
var source = Enumerable.Range(0, 12)
    .Select(i =>  new ListItem(DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1 * i).ToString("MMM yyyy")));
DdlYearMonth.DataSource = source;
DdlYearMonth.DataBind();
```

The `Range` is similar to a  for-loop. In the `Select` i'm creating `ListItems` from the `DateTimes` (starting today, going back one month each loop). [`ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) takes a format string which converts the datetime to a string with your specified format.

[Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)

If you also want to set the ListItem's `Value` property to the month number(f.e. 1 for january):

```
var source = Enumerable.Range(0, 12)
   .Select(i => DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1 * i))
   .Select(d => new { Text = d.ToString("MMM yyyy"), Value = d.Month.ToString() });
DdlYearMonth.DataTextField = "Text";
DdlYearMonth.DataValueField = "Value";
DdlYearMonth.DataSource = source;
DdlYearMonth.DataBind();
```

Comment: Is it possible to throw in value 1-12 for months instead of having value = "nov 2012" in the dropdownlist option?

Comment: @sindrem: Edited my answer to show how to set the text **and** the value of the ListItems.

Comment: Your LINQ-fu is strong, young one.  Nice clean and concise solution.

Comment: Instead of setting `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` with `DataSource+DataBind` you could also use a `foreach` and add the ListItems manually(with the value).